# How can I fix my yaxis-label on my dotchart, which appears all too chunked up together? I need more spacing

Tags: charts, axis-labels

Multiple columns dotchart and wrong ylabel

Hi there,

I am working for my final exam of programming for university.
The assignment consists of working dataframes and creating different types of plot.

I am trying trying to create a DOTCHART, but I am having issues with the labels of the y axis, as they are not showing properly and are all too close together.

```
items <- c(ftprint5$Food_product)

dotchart(ftprint5$`Eutrophying_emissions_per_1000kcal_(gPOe_per_1000kcal)`, labels=items, cex=0.9, xlab="eutrophying emissions, ylab="Food item", pch=20, bg='green')
```

[This is a part of the table I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMZ4l.png)
[This is the chart I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C69N.png)

I thank you very much in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am a complete beginner and I am trying to carry on with my work with guides I find on the internet.